# Inversion of Control and deep dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

[Edited to narrow down the question scope]:

For simplicity sake, I have a Winforms application:

- main function opens FormA
- FormA has a button that creates and opens FormB
- FormB needs to send something to the server, so it creates an instance of WonderService class that has this capability.
- WonderClass needs ILogger to log the success/failure and IConfig to read the service Url.

Now, the question is, if I want my system to be designed with IOC in mind, how do I pass ILogger and IConfig down the stream if FormA/B don't need it?

Comment: This question is very broad and might, therefore, be unsuited for Stack Overflow. Your question is in risk of being closed over this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, @Steven, I am actually looking for an answer to a very specific problem of passing dependencies. Will try to edit the question.

Comment: Don't forget to add a comment once you did; Stack Overflow doesn't notify about question updates, only about new comments.

Comment: Edited to narrow down the scope of the question

Comment: you shouldn't pass anything "down".  Instead, just inject the logger into the place that needs the logger

Comment: @jwells131313, if none of the forms need the logger, should I still pass it to them from the main() which is the application root? What about the WonderClass, should it also be injected into FormA and then FormB?

Comment: If none of the forms need the logger, don't inject the logger anywhere (why would you?). Also from your description sounds like only FormB interacts with WonderClass, so only inject WonderClass into FormB

Comment: Thanks @jwells131313. That makes sense. The question then what will instantiate FormB?